# to trim a any substring inside bracket in the string

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have string in python :

```
line=r"X:\folder\Code\Mod\ACCSC1C1.c 351: Error -> Warning 550 Symbol XXX (line 34) not accessed"
```

and I want to trim this line like to remove (line 34).
But for different case line number varies like line may be like:

```
X:\ACCSC1C1.c 333: Error -> Warning 4' (line 536) not accessed
X:\ACCSddC1.c 633: Error -> Warning 8' (line 111) not accessed
```

so my output should come like:

```
X:\ACCSC1C1.c 333: Error -> Warning 4'  not accessed
X:\ACCSddC1.c 633: Error -> Warning 8'  not accessed
```

I used wildcard '*' but it is not working even eliminating brackets () showing some errors , usually am using re module.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re
line=r"X:\folder\Code\Mod\ACCSC1C1.c 351: Error -> Warning 550 Symbol XXX (line 34) not accessed"
re.sub("\(line \d+\)", '', line)
```

> > 'X:\folder\Code\Mod\ACCSC1C1.c 351: Error -> Warning 550 Symbol XXX  not accessed'

From the documentation for `sub`:

> re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0) Return the string
>   obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping occurrences of
>   pattern in string by the replacement repl. If the pattern isn’t found,
>   string is returned unchanged.

Comment: @PranjayKaparuwan Glad to help

Comment: Hey @Arunmu if the lines like:

X:\\VDR-BRZ-SP\\Code\\Mod\\VARRC\\VARRC1C1.c: lines 5887, 5890, 5893, 5896]"

X:\\VDR-BRZ-SP\\Code\\Mod\\VARRC\\VARRC1C1.c: lines 53337

I need to remove  "lines 1234" from  that line

Comment: hey I got it !!!
we can try :

re.sub(r"line \d+ | line \d+, \d+ | lines \d+ | line \d+ | lines \d+, \d+, \d+ | ", '', line)

the above includes some combinations, "|" this symbol represents OR